# Azure Container Instance Mount point permissions

Tags: permissions, azure, docker, mount

I am having some problems with a website that I am running on Azure Container Instances.  I've got a wordpress docker image pulling from a private azure container registry, and I'm mounting a file share from an Azure storage account and I'm doing all of this with ARM templates in line with this [tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files).

I've used the example at the bottom of the article.  It's all been working fine but suddenly I can't seem to access files on the file share.

I have tried chmod to change permissions: `chmod -R 755 myfolder` and the command runs but does not update the permissions.

I've also set "readOnly": false on both the volume definition and volumeMount definition in the ARM template.

If I do `cat /proc/mounts` I can see the `cifs` mount which is mounted rw but it has `dir_mode=0700` and  `file_mode=0700` which I think is where the problem lies.

I'm not sure if something has changed in azure container instances, or perhaps the docker build pipeline (incidentally, I had changed to the new Ubuntu build agent in VSTS but I tested the legacy linux preview agent but same result)

Any ideas on how I can change the dir_mode and file_mode settings? Are there parameters in the ARM template to change these? I couldn't see any references in the ARM template reference on the microsoft site.

Thanks in advance

Rob

Answer (score 1):

There is a **readOnly** parameter that you can set to **false** and see if that makes a difference but 700 is not even readonly.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/2018-09-01/containergroups

```
"azureFile": {
  "shareName": "string",
  "readOnly": boolean,
  "storageAccountName": "string",
  "storageAccountKey": "string"
},
```

It looks like there is an open issue in GitHub for this issue.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/19017

I recommend you open your own or weigh in on existing issue.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem and got it fixed.

i am using CLI though.

## what was missing

`az storage share policy create --help`

## what i did

i added a share policy with the all the permisions (read-write-list) needed and it worked.
i have no longer the access permission problem on the ACI

hope this will help